# Issue with the count in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by

I want the count of the one column and I have 5 columns in FROM clause but it is giving wrong count as I have included all my columns that are in the from clause. I don't want that particular column in the GROUP BY clause.

If I remove that column from GROUP BY clause it throws the following error:

> ERROR:  column "pt.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used
>   in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT distinct on (pu.id) pu.id,
>   pt.name as package_name, c...

E.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a,b,c,count(d),e
FROM table GROUP BY a,b,c,d,e ORDER BY a
```

From this I want to remove e from the GROUP BY.

How can I remove that column from GROUP BY so that I can get correct count?

Comment: I'm little confused of using `distinct on (a)` and then `group by`. Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: I am newbie in the PostgreSQL. Can you please suggest me any solution. How can I get the count for the column d.

Comment: It's hard to give you a solution if I don't know what your goal is. Use real column names and real query, describe relations between involved tables - then it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Updated after rereading the question.</sup>
You are mixing `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT ON`. What you want (how I understand it) can be done with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html) combined with a `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a)
       a, b, c
     , count(d) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c) AS d_ct
     , e
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY a, d_ct DESC;
```

Window functions require PostgreSQL 8.4 ore later.

What happens here?

1. Count in `d_ct` how many identical sets of `(a,b,c)` there are in the table with non-null values for `d`.
2. Pick exactly one row per `a`. If you don't `ORDER BY` more than just `a`, a random row will be picked.
3. In my example I `ORDER BY` `d_ct DESC` in addition, so a pseudo-random row out of the set with the highest `d_ct` will be picked.

---

Another, slightly different interpretation of what you might need, with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a)
       a, b, c
     , count(d) AS d_ct
     , min(e)   AS min_e             -- aggregate e in some way
FROM   t
GROUP  BY a, b, c
ORDER  BY a, d_ct DESC;
```

`GROUP BY` is applied *before* `DISTINCT ON`, so the result is very similar to the one above, only the value for `e` / `min_e` is different.